# Puppeteer with Headless_shell?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to work on puppeteer with headless_shell to avoid library dependencies in Linux. When i tried `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'out/Release/headless_shell'})` the browser is created. But When I tried, `const page = await browser.newPage();` The process stopped right there without any errors.
    For different version for headless_shell, i'm getting this error.

```
 (node:17176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
    [0906/155318.398013:ERROR:icu_util.cc(172)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
    [0906/155318.398147:FATAL:content_main_delegate.cc(58)] Check failed: false. 
    #0 0x000002abf89c base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
    #1 0x000002a45ca0 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
    #2 0x0000029edc23 content::ContentMainDelegate::TerminateForFatalInitializationError()
    #3 0x0000029f5202 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
    #4 0x000003d6b528 service_manager::Main()
    #5 0x0000029ee4a1 content::ContentMain()
    #6 0x000002ae077d headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
    #7 0x000002ae0808 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
    #8 0x000002a2e84a headless::HeadlessShellMain()
    #9 0x7f38923ac830 __libc_start_main
    #10 0x00000124f02a _start
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is permissions of the directories/files.

When puppeteer was installed, the permissions were default owner of nobody: but not all files had group or others bits set (i.e. 600 or 700). Puppeteer was installed as `npm install -g puppeteer` and it is run as the local user. The fix was to chmod the files to set the group and others bits to match the "users".

```
cd out/Release/headless_shell #or wherever the file is
find . -type d | xargs -L1 -Ixx sudo chmod 755 xx
find . -type f -perm /u+x | xargs -L1 -Ixx sudo chmod 755 xx
find . -type f -not -perm /u+x | xargs -L1 -Ixx sudo chmod 644 xx
```

PS: The actual error is shown as `Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received`, and the issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2519 discussed it in depth.